# Translate text box data dynamically using google translate and jquery in c# asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I have a web site which is in English. I have used  google translate in order to convert it to arabic language.So now I have 2 options for my web site I can choose English or Arabic. Now the problem which I have is  whenever I enter data inside text box i want it to translate dynamically in arabic and show it inside text box using ajax or jquery.?And site is built in asp.net

Comment: you can use focus-out event of jQuery to call service of google to translate textbox values.

Comment: I'm using google translate how to request google translate from focus-out to translate data ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some idea what you can do if you want

```
$('#txtId').focusOut(function() {

    //Call the Google API
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data : "v=1.0&q="+  $('#txtId').val()+"&langpair=en|es",
        success : function(iData){
            //update the value
             $('#txtId').val(iData["responseData"]["translatedText"]);      
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ }
    });
});
```

this is just an idea change it according your requirement.

Comment: Supposing say i change my keyboard setting to arabic and then is it possible to convert this data from arabic  to English using google api in order to store it in database MS SQL?